SSH Login when the Server is in Sleep
My desktop computer(an archlinux running on that) goes to sleep after a period of inactivity. When it is in sleep mode, attempting to log in via SSH fails. Is there a way to successfully log in via SSH while the computer is in sleep mode?
I want the desktop computer to wake up when I attempt to log in via SSH, just like it wakes up when I touch the mouse. The computer should go back to sleep after I log out of the SSH session. Is there a way to achieve this?

There's a big difference between "USB input" and "TCP input".  If the system is asleep then it won't accept TCP connections  so won't wake on on ssh.    You might get lucky with "wake on lan" packets; that'd be my first guess.  Send a WoL wait a minute then try ssh.
